# Return boolean values in dynamic jQuery based on wp_localize_script

Tags: jquery, wordpress, localization, boolean

Here is my localization code...

```
global $post;
$meta_value = (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_full_static_area', true) ==  'on') ? 'on' : 'off';
$localize_array = array(
    'moon' => $meta_value
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'moonscript-dynamic', TEMPLATE_URI . '/js/moonscript-dynamic.php', false, THEME_VERSION , true );
wp_localize_script( 'moonscript-dynamic', 'wplocal', $localize_array );
```

`wplocal` returns whether my `post_meta` is on or off. I'm using `wplocal` (the value inside my  wp_localize_script) in my jQuery and of course it returns on/off appropriately.
How do I write that to display jQuery code if on, and not display if false?

Here is what I wrote...

```
if(wplocal.moon === on ){
    function dynamicAdjust() {
        jQuery('#main-home').css('margin-top', jQuery(window).height());        
    }
}
```

I pass the function inside a ready function, the code works, but I am trying to make it dynamic based on a boolean value? Should be easy, but I am still learning jQuery, and incorporating the localization  confuses me on how to write it true/false...

Similar to wrapping a block of code in a PHP if statement. It orginally was like that till I found I needed to localize the dynamic script.

Comment: Does your filename contains white-spaces? `moonscript-  dynamic.php`?

Comment: no sorry just an accident on the stackoverflow posting

Comment: was trying to format it and must have added spaces on accident will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a programming logic and syntax issue. You should really search for nice tutorials, like [here](https://tutsplus.com) or similar sites. The [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) manuals are a must.

You are checking for a string, so it should be `if(wplocal.moon === 'on')`. With **quotes** in `'on'`.

And you do the checks **inside** the function, not outside:

```
function dynamicAdjust() {
    if( wplocal.moon === 'on' ){
        jQuery('#main-home').css('margin-top', jQuery(window).height());        
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the links, I normally search for tutorials, but this one was different I wasn't sure where to look... I really appreciate you teaching me and helping a fella out...